# xamarin form is giving me deployment error on phisical device

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, mobile

i just started xamarin form as a blank page when i run it on an emulator it work just fine but too slow, then i tried to open it in my device (a xiaomi rednote 8) but it is giving me a deployment error ADB0010
the device is already set in allow debug mode.
i already uninstalled and reinstalled xamarin, my version of visual studio is 2019, looking around i've tried to run visual studio as admin and unchecked the shared runtime but still nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i finally found out, the problem is not the software but xiaomi, the debug mode is not the only thing that need to be checked, th "Install via USB" option in the Developer mode was off, a simple switch on was enough.